# Should I use mongoengine.Document or models.Model when Using mongodb but also django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, model, document

Until now I worked with models.Model .
But currently i need to work with Mongodb.
Should I continue with models.Model or should I use mongoengine.Document?

Any suggestions/(dis-)advantages you know?

```
class ViewerRequestLog(mongoengine.Document):
VS
class ViewerRequestLog(models.Model):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any but I will suggest mongoengine.Document as it is more flexible and very dynamic.
Go through: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use djongo instead of mongoengine and the best part of djongo is that you don't need to change the Django ORM. Same kind of querying like before when using traditional SQL Databases.

Djongo (The only connector that let's you use Django with MongoDB without changing the Django ORM) : https://github.com/nesdis/djongo